# Sub Domain and Domain level Relative Path for HTML

Tags: php, html

I have an Image in a folder "img" at root level. I am referencing it using a relative path from the root as:

```
<img src="/Image/image.JPG" />
```

Now the thing is i created a subdomain as well which point to a directory inside root called "docs" . So docs..com will redirect to root/docs/

If i access index.php via /docs/index.php all dependencies are loaded correctly but when i load it via docs. it goes to index.php but all dependencies try to get loaded from /docs instead of .

I have used "/" for all the dependencies to start from root.

Update:
As suggested i can put image in subdirectory as well. But that is not the only dependencies. I have a lot of css/js scattered in my code. they all are referenced using root by using "/" in front of their path from ROOT. problem is when i use subdomain ROOT changes to "ROOT/docs".

Comment: try `<img src="../Image/image.JPG" />`

Comment: it will break if i navigate from main domain . ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your directories are structured. Can you do `<img src="/subdomaindirectory/Image/image.JPG" />`? That would link to `http://subdomain.domain.com/Image/image.JPG`

Comment: I can do that. But that is not the only dependencies. I have a lot of css/js scattered in my code. they all are referenced using root by using "/" in front of their path from ROOT. problem is when i use subdomain ROOT changes to "ROOT/docs".

Comment: Using apache? Should be able to use some rewriting .htaccess magic, though I'm no expert. If you want you could add the .htaccess tag and reword the question slightly to ask about it. There might also be an existing question that is similar.